# Sharing a mex64 file across computers

Tags: dll, matlab, windows-7-x64

I have a mex64 dll compiled on my machine. I used Matlab 2009b with VS2008 Pro to compile the dll.  The dll works fine on my Matlab installation.

I want a colleague to use the dll so I sent it to him and he gets the following error message when trying to use the dll:

> ??? Invalid MEX-file 'filename.mexw64': The specified module could not be found.

My current assumption is that this is caused because he uses an older Matlab version or missing a dll that I have. I ran dependency checker and asked him to check that he has all the listed dlls.

I am still waiting for him to confirm his Matlab version.

What other reasons can cause this and can the Matlab version make a difference? (I mean R2009a when I have R2009B and not a huge version diff)

---

The other person has Matlab R2009a. Shouldn't the mex just work if I compile it on my computer and deliver it to him?

Does this only leave a missing dependent dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dll was a wrapper for MySql access. We ended up using Matlab's ODBC and the MySql Connector.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is strange, but I can confirm it exists.

Using pre-built libraries for matlab that are correctly installed and in the path, I sometimes get the same error. If I type in the function name at the command-line, the function is visible and will auto-complete. However, the function will not initialize until I 'cd' into the directory with the .mexw64 library file.

```
>> AndorInitialize('')
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\andor\AndorInitialize.mexw64': The
specified module could not be found.

>> path

        MATLABPATH

    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\andor
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\andor\camera files
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\andor\m files
    ... etc
```

It turns out this is due to missing dependencies, which shouldn't be missing. To resolve the issue, use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (free, lightweight) to identify what's missing. The mathworks explains this.

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2RQL4L/

In my case, two DLL's weren't showing up properly, even though they were on my system and in the path. I copied the DLL's into the windows/system32 folder and the library functions now work correctly. What's particularly strange is that the same library worked on my computer a few days ago (prior to the moving the DLL's).

Comment: Thanks! It was resolved differently, but I hope this answer will help others

Answer (score 0):

In general, MEX files should work across different versions of Matlab; in particular, they should be forward-compatible. You're right; sounds like a dll problem.

If you built it with Visual Studio, it may be linked to the Visual C++ Runtime. This is a set of libraries that is not installed on Windows by default. The "redistributable" for it can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=BD2A6171-E2D6-4230-B809-9A8D7548C1B6&displaylang=en); having your coworker install that could resolve the problem. If that doesn't work, you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check for other unsatisfied DLL dependencies.

Normally, configuring Matlab's "mex -setup" to use the Lcc compiler that's distributed with Matlab could be a way around this, but it's not supported for 64-bit Windows AFAIK.

Also, are you sure he has the 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure he has the 64-bit version. We are going through the Dlls using dependency walker right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible source of the problem could be that you compiled in debug mode. The Visual C++ redistributables only support release mode.

Comment: I did not use a debug flag when compiling so I am pretty sure it is in release mode.